# Pocket-size Tehillim with trop

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, tehilim-psalms, trop-cantillation

Is there a clear, pocket-sized safer Tehillim, printed with trop ? Ideally, the girsah is corrected against the Keter Aram Soba. Everything I've seen is either fairly large or lacks trop, but I live out of town, so maybe the 'olam here will know of something

Answer (score 1):

The Koren Tehillim Lev Avot series comes in a compact/pocket size.

See a sample page [here](https://korenpub.com/cdn/shop/files/book_tehilim_lev_avot_sample.pdf?v=18259199085185269508) - (there is a short introduction but if you jump to p.10 of 12 you will see the print with the trop) - see below

There are a selection of designs available e.g.
[Purple](https://www.greenfieldjudaica.com/koren-tehillim-lev-avot-purple-BK-KTLAPU.html) / [tie-dye](https://www.greenfieldjudaica.com/koren-tehillim-lev-avot-tie-dye-BK-KTLATD.html) / [blue](https://www.greenfieldjudaica.com/koren-tehillim-lev-avot-blue-BK-KTLAB.html)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tanach simanim has a "mechulak" version.  It comes in a cardboard box with 17 paperback volumes.

https://www.feldheim.com/tanach-simanim-hebrew-only+edition-Mechulak

Comment: Not to nitpick, but this is larger than the smallest one I saw with trop (Kehot, Ohel Yosef Yitzchok), which I'd consider, despite the fact that I would ignore the bits that make it a go-to for Chabad (bi'ur by one of their rabbeim, letters in the back)